# Why is search keyword going across apps on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac

I just found out if a keyword is searched inside of Google Chrome on a Mac, then if I go to the Terminal app and search there, the keyword will go across there.

That is different from what I know before: each app's search is independent and they would not go across. How come it is happening and is there a way to make them independent?

(this Mac is still running Mavericks but I am wondering if High Sierra is doing the same thing)

Comment: This has been the way search works since, well around 10.7 (Lion?) maybe. Previous to that, yes it was a per-app basis.

Comment: so there is any way that an app can actually "see" what you are searching in other apps?  For example, if I am searching the confidential keyword `ABCDE` in the Terminal app, can Google Chrome potentially also know this keyword and sends it back to their server?